# SQL Statement to order by one column if another column doesn't exist in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, sorry for what may be a simple question, however, I cannot get my head around how to solve this SQL query which is used within a web application I have built.

I have a number of tables within my database and they need to be ordered differently when displayed on the website. Currently my code is:

```
//get the data from a table (request from the user)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$TableName` ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Get the template of the table 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableIndex WHERE TableName = '$TableName'";
$resultTemplate = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultTemplate)) {
    $Template = $row['Template'];
            }
```

This gets the data from one table and then checks what pre defined template to use to display the information on the screen.

An example of a template can be seen below:

```
echo '      
                    <thead>
                     <tr class="row-1">
                        <th class="column-1">Club</th>
                        <th class="column-2">P</th>
                        <th class="column-3">Shots</th>
                        <th class="column-4">Pts</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

                    if ($count == 0){
                    $output = 'error';
                }else {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $ID = $row['ID'];
                    $one = $row['ColumnOne'];
                    $two = $row['ColumnTwo'];
                    $three = $row['ColumnThree'];
                    $four = $row['ColumnFour'];

                    $output =' 
                        <tr class="d1">
                        <td>'.$one.'</td>
                        <td>'.$two.'</td>
                        <td>'.$three.'</td>
                        <td>'.$four.'</td>
                       </tr>

                  ';

        echo $output;
```

I now need to amend the `$sql = SELECT * FROM $TableName` to have **ORDER BY** cases, such as;

- If "ColumnFive" exists then "ORDER BY ColumnFour DESC"
- If "ColumnSix" exists then "ORDER BY ColumnFive DESC"
- If "ColumnSeven" exists then don't order

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `isset()` to check if the column key exists and then `usort()` to sort the result accordingly in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check if column exists

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$TableName` LIKE 'ColumnName'");
$exists = (mysql_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
```

then build your main query accordingly